# Snapping feature in osmdroid when drawing a Polygon

Tags: android, gis, osmdroid, snapping

In ArcGis we have snapping feature thats allow us to connect new drawing item to another overlay on map. here is detail of this feature.
[ArcGIS snapping feature](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/editing-fundamentals/about-snapping.htm)

but in osmdroid how can i use this structure?
i find [this document](https://osmdroid.github.io/osmdroid/javadocs/osmdroid-android/debug/index.html?org/osmdroid/views/overlay/Overlay.Snappable.html) of osmdroid. but i need sample code to find how to use snapping in osmdroid.